# apply anchor to background image in CSS

Tags: html, css, background, anchor, background-image

If I have a DIV of height 200px with a background applied to it of height 175px, is there a way that I can wrap an anchor around the image *only* ?

```
<div style="background: url('http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/downloads/Image/11218.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-position: bottom;" class="block block2 ">
    <ul class="elem"></ul>
    <span class="left_border"></span>       
</div>
```

Nothing is jumping out at me other than restructuring my markup, which i'd rather avoid doing at this stage.

Comment: No, there is no image to wrap around, only a background. Why not use display:block and change your DIV to an A-tag?

Comment: A background image isn't a dom element so wrapping anything around it is impossible. Your bet is to add a link and make it 175 pixels tall. It will give the illusion of being 'wrapped' around the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you give the parent div (the one with the background) some css: `position:relative`

you can then create an anchor like so:

```
.block2 a.block_link {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:175px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
    background-image:url(transparent.png);
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

**Please note**: apply a transparent png to the link to fix the IE bug.. just a 1px by 1px transparent image will be fine..

```
<div style="background: url('http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/downloads/Image/11218.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-position: bottom;" class="block block2 ">
    <ul class="elem"></ul>
    <span class="left_border"></span>    
    <a href="#" class="block_link">&nbsp;</a>   
</div>
```

To keep the other elements above the link, i.e the ul and span.. add the css of

```
.block2 ul,.block2 span {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: not sure what the downvotes are for.. this is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div in, position it absolutely over top of your background image and set the width and the height to the dimensions of the background image, then wrap an anchor link around that div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these:

```
<div style="position:relative; background: url('http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/downloads/Image/11218.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-position: bottom;" class="block block2 ">
   <ul class="elem"></ul>
   <span class="left_border"></span>
   <a href='#'>link</a>       
</div>
```

css for link `<a>`:

```
.block a{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:25px; // spared height: from the top;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-99999px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0; // or you can try with top:175px;
}
```

Comment: You are covering the whole div.. this is not what the OP wanted.. (i have also already answered this 10 minutes ago with the correct answer).. you've got unnecessary CSS in there ( `display:block; overflow:hidden;` ) and your answer will bug out on IE

Comment: @DannyHearnah Are you sure about IE bug?

Comment: and you just edited your answer after mine. see the edit time. and my answer post time.

Comment: I edited mine to change my spelling error.. and yes, in IE if you don't have a bg image the text of other elements will stop the link from being clickable

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you can't technically put a link around a background image, but I assume you just want to make that area clickable maybe?

HTML:

```
<div id="my-div" style="background: url('http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/downloads/Image/11218.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; background-position: bottom;" class="block block2 ">
    <ul class="elem"></ul>
    <span class="left_border"></span>      
    <a href="http://www.example.com/"></a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-div {
position: relative;
}
#my-div a {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 175px;
width: 100%;
}
```

It's not clear from your question how you want the link to work in conjunction with the UL, but you'd either have to position the list below the link area or with a higher z-index if it needs to be clickable.

Comment: This is also wrong.. the OP wanted it to cover the background image, the background image sits at the bottom of the div.. this link sits at the top of the div. and also bugs out on IE